# Adding metadata as annotation to correlation heat-map

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation, pheatmap

I m trying to generate  a sample to sample correlation heat-map which I m able to do it.

Is it possible to add metadata to the correlation heat map just as we can do for normal heatmap?

My code

```
library(Hmisc)
library(pheatmap)

    df1 <- read.csv("figure1/TCGA_data/BEAT_AML/TCGA_AML/analysis/TCGA_expr_EF.txt",sep = "\t",header = T) 
    
    dim(df1)
    names(df1)
    df1 <- df1[-c(1)]
    names(df1)
    data1 <- df1
    gen <- data1
    
    head(gen)
    dim(gen)
    
    gendat <- t(gen)
    gendat <- gen
    dim(gendat)
    macolor = colorRampPalette(c("navyblue","white","red"))(100)
    cor_5 <- rcorr(as.matrix(PCA_map_rlog[-c(1:2)]))
    
    
    cor_5 <- rcorr(as.matrix(gendat))
    M <- cor_5$r
    str(M)
    p_mat <- cor_5$P
    row_names <- rownames(M)
    
    head(M)
    
    plot_data_pheatmap <- pheatmap(M, color = rev(macolor), 
                      clustering_method = "complete", fontsize_row = 8, fontsize_col = 8,show_colnames = FALSE,show_rownames = FALSE)
    dev.off()
```

[image: correlation heatmap]

Metadata small subset

```
aa <- dput(head(b))
structure(list(name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("TCGA-AB-2803", 
"TCGA-AB-2805", "TCGA-AB-2806", "TCGA-AB-2807", "TCGA-AB-2808", 
"TCGA-AB-2810", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2812", "TCGA-AB-2813", 
"TCGA-AB-2814", "TCGA-AB-2815", "TCGA-AB-2816", "TCGA-AB-2817", 
"TCGA-AB-2818", "TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2820", "TCGA-AB-2821", 
"TCGA-AB-2822", "TCGA-AB-2823", "TCGA-AB-2824", "TCGA-AB-2825", 
"TCGA-AB-2826", "TCGA-AB-2828", "TCGA-AB-2830", "TCGA-AB-2832", 
"TCGA-AB-2833", "TCGA-AB-2834", "TCGA-AB-2835", "TCGA-AB-2836", 
"TCGA-AB-2837", "TCGA-AB-2838", "TCGA-AB-2839", "TCGA-AB-2840", 
"TCGA-AB-2841", "TCGA-AB-2842", "TCGA-AB-2843", "TCGA-AB-2844", 
"TCGA-AB-2845", "TCGA-AB-2846", "TCGA-AB-2847", "TCGA-AB-2848", 
"TCGA-AB-2849", "TCGA-AB-2851", "TCGA-AB-2853", "TCGA-AB-2854", 
"TCGA-AB-2855", "TCGA-AB-2856", "TCGA-AB-2857", "TCGA-AB-2858", 
"TCGA-AB-2859", "TCGA-AB-2860", "TCGA-AB-2861", "TCGA-AB-2862", 
"TCGA-AB-2863", "TCGA-AB-2865", "TCGA-AB-2866", "TCGA-AB-2867", 
"TCGA-AB-2868", "TCGA-AB-2869", "TCGA-AB-2870", "TCGA-AB-2871", 
"TCGA-AB-2872", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2874", "TCGA-AB-2875", 
"TCGA-AB-2877", "TCGA-AB-2879", "TCGA-AB-2880", "TCGA-AB-2881", 
"TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2885", "TCGA-AB-2886", 
"TCGA-AB-2887", "TCGA-AB-2888", "TCGA-AB-2889", "TCGA-AB-2890", 
"TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2895", "TCGA-AB-2896", "TCGA-AB-2897", 
"TCGA-AB-2898", "TCGA-AB-2899", "TCGA-AB-2900", "TCGA-AB-2901", 
"TCGA-AB-2903", "TCGA-AB-2904", "TCGA-AB-2908", "TCGA-AB-2909", 
"TCGA-AB-2910", "TCGA-AB-2911", "TCGA-AB-2912", "TCGA-AB-2913", 
"TCGA-AB-2914", "TCGA-AB-2915", "TCGA-AB-2916", "TCGA-AB-2917", 
"TCGA-AB-2918", "TCGA-AB-2919", "TCGA-AB-2920", "TCGA-AB-2921", 
"TCGA-AB-2924", "TCGA-AB-2925", "TCGA-AB-2927", "TCGA-AB-2928", 
"TCGA-AB-2929", "TCGA-AB-2930", "TCGA-AB-2931", "TCGA-AB-2932", 
"TCGA-AB-2933", "TCGA-AB-2934", "TCGA-AB-2935", "TCGA-AB-2936", 
"TCGA-AB-2937", "TCGA-AB-2938", "TCGA-AB-2939", "TCGA-AB-2940", 
"TCGA-AB-2941", "TCGA-AB-2942", "TCGA-AB-2943", "TCGA-AB-2944", 
"TCGA-AB-2946", "TCGA-AB-2948", "TCGA-AB-2949", "TCGA-AB-2950", 
"TCGA-AB-2952", "TCGA-AB-2954", "TCGA-AB-2955", "TCGA-AB-2956", 
"TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2963", "TCGA-AB-2964", "TCGA-AB-2965", 
"TCGA-AB-2966", "TCGA-AB-2967", "TCGA-AB-2969", "TCGA-AB-2970", 
"TCGA-AB-2971", "TCGA-AB-2972", "TCGA-AB-2973", "TCGA-AB-2975", 
"TCGA-AB-2976", "TCGA-AB-2977", "TCGA-AB-2978", "TCGA-AB-2979", 
"TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2981", "TCGA-AB-2982", "TCGA-AB-2983", 
"TCGA-AB-2984", "TCGA-AB-2985", "TCGA-AB-2986", "TCGA-AB-2987", 
"TCGA-AB-2988", "TCGA-AB-2990", "TCGA-AB-2991", "TCGA-AB-2992", 
"TCGA-AB-2993", "TCGA-AB-2994", "TCGA-AB-2995", "TCGA-AB-2996", 
"TCGA-AB-2998", "TCGA-AB-2999", "TCGA-AB-3000", "TCGA-AB-3001", 
"TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-3005", "TCGA-AB-3006", "TCGA-AB-3007", 
"TCGA-AB-3008", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-3011", "TCGA-AB-3012"
), class = "factor"), FAB = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", 
"nc"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to add the FAB column as my annotation to the final correlation heatmap.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

My expression [TCGA_expr_EF.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OnMBqpF9O692KaQwUs6Cu9fpwtPA69PP/view?usp=sharing) used and my [metadata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bIEw9SpGPlk9buPwtJzrA4cbV2ivvl3k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just a note that it is misleading to use a diverging colormap here when all your values are above `0`. You can force the colormap to center at `0` (at least you can with `gplots::heatmap.2()`) or just use a sequential one instead.

Comment: yes since these are gene expression all of them are in positive. "You can force the colormap to center at 0". this is absolutely new for me how do I implement this one ?

Comment: `Hmisc::rcorr()` performs a correlation, either `pearson`  (default) or `spearman`. In either case the values can range from `-1` to `1`. So it looks to me like the values in the heatmap are representing correlations based on gene expression, not the gene expression values themselves. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `pheatmap()` so I can't  help you on how to make it do that but I'd guess it's possible. Perhaps you can add it to your question and someone else can chime in on that.

Comment: here it Im running sample to sample clustering .

Comment: Right - but you're clustering based on the correlation coefficients. The distance metric for the clustering function is based off the correlation results you feed into the heatmap function.

Comment: yes thanks for the answer will give it a try I think i will try this with complex-heat map as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add colorbar annotation layers to the rows and columns in `pheatmap()` using `annotation_row`/`annotation_col` and `annotation_colors` arguments.

Your example was far from minimal so I used a small included dataset here.

Also as noted in the comments, your correlation values range from `-1` to `1` so it's misleading to use a diverging colormap that is not centered at `0`. I offer two possible solutions. First, you could center it at `0` using the `breaks` argument in `pheatmap()` which will emphasize that most of your values are actually quite similar and all highly mutually correlated. Second, you could use a sequential palette such as in my second example which will emphasize the differences between the samples.

```r
library(Hmisc)
library(pheatmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridisLite)

# prep data
d <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car") %>% 
  mutate(car = abbreviate(car)) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("car") %>% 
  as.matrix()

# run correlation
c <- d %>% 
  t() %>% 
  rcorr(type = "pearson") %>% 
  .[["r"]]

# create diverging colormap
macolor <- colorRampPalette(c("navyblue","white","red"))(100)

# prep sample annotations
samp_annot <- data.frame(row.names = rownames(d), cyl = factor(d[,2]))
# prep annotation colors
annot_col <- list(cyl = setNames(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A"), unique(samp_annot$cyl)))

# set divergent palette to center at 0 with breaks
c %>%
  pheatmap(
    mat = .,
    color = rev(macolor),
    breaks = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 101),
    clustering_method = "complete",
    annotation_row = samp_annot,
    annotation_col = samp_annot,
    annotation_colors = annot_col[1],
    show_colnames = FALSE,
    show_rownames = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

```r
# use sequential palette
c %>%
  pheatmap(
    mat = .,
    color = viridis(100, option = "A"),
    clustering_method = "complete",
    annotation_row = samp_annot,
    annotation_col = samp_annot,
    annotation_colors = annot_col[1],
    show_colnames = FALSE,
    show_rownames = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: it works really good ...thanks a lot